# Overleaf 'forgets' user defined commands in different tex files

Tags: macros, overleaf, include

I am working on my master thesis and thus have a lot of different tex files which get included in main.tex (using `\include{}`). However I now face the problem that all commands I define in the preamble of main.tex are "forgotten" when switching to another tex document, say introduction.tex.

Concretely, when I type a user defined command in main.tex, overleaf will autocomplete with the right amount of arguments,
[image]

but when I do the same in another file, overleaf will not even remember that command

[image]

unless I have already used it, in which case it suggests it without arguments.

[image]

This is the first time I have worked with included files, and so I have no idea how to solve this. A google search and Overleafs documentation have not solved this either.
Is there any way to "import" these commands or make Overleaf remember these definitions? I do admit it is a minor issue, but it is quite frustrating me.

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be posed to Overleaf’s Helpdesk. Their support staff is top-notch.

Comment: @Mico Ok, I will do this. I am going to keep tis question up in case anyone else has the same problem (and to refer the help staff to this question), but feel free to delete this if it breaks site rules.

Comment: I actually experience the same problem. I would appreciate if you post the solution of the help staff (if any.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overleaf's autocomplete feature scans the current .tex file in the editor for commands that have been defined and previously used. It also provides autocompletion for commands provided through some frequently used packages if these are referenced via usepackage in the current tex file. Commands that are defined in a separate preamble won't be shown in the autocomplete list until they are used for the first time in the current .tex file.